Stern-Gerlach experiment questions
Assume that we have a Stern-Gerlach device for spin 1/2 particles, with the magnetic field and its gradient in the z-direction.
I understand that if the spin is +1/2 then in the Heisenberg picture, the force will be upwards, so the expectation value of position z will be positive.

Does this mean that the particle will necessarily deflect upwards? Is the probability for a negative deflection exactly zero? It seems to me that the expectation value being positive doesn't imply that the actual measurement of the position will always be positive.

In the light of the previous question, if the answer is that there's a small probability that a particle with +1/2 spin will be deflected downwards, can we ever exactly know its spin using only one Stern-Gerlach device? I guess, if we had many sequential SG devices, we could be quite certain of its spin if it deflected say 99/100 times upwards (hence spin = +1/2)

Now comes the part that I'm most confused about. If the particle is in a superposition of spin states, it seems that the expectation value of its z position, could be anything. In fact, I think that a (normalized) state $(|+> + |->)$, would give $<z>=0$. So I don't understand how a superposed spin can lead to only two deflections.



Basically the electron has a magnetic property (spin) that can cause its deflection up or down, we never know what spin there is to start. Also once we detect/deflect the electron we have upset/reset it .... it has a new spin, we don't know which unless we detect/deflect it again.   Saying the particle is in "superposition" is quantum baloney .... preferred by the quantum mathematicians .... but probably not to meaningful to the quantum physicists.
